# log stacktrace from another user with error: Unfortunately, Application has stopped

Tags: android, xamarin.android, runtime-error, logcat

This is an information question rather than a technical question. I have an app in Google Market. I need to know stracktrace of errors happens in other phones.

I have investigated but I have not seen anything about it. Does anyone know if Google offers some service to look at the errors that your application is giving in the market and thus to be able to reproduce it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Analytics things tend to do that, like Crashlytics

Answer (score 0):

Open your app at the developer console and select "disruptions and ANR". Here you can select on of disruptions you have, then you can see error stack trace!

Or you can use appmetrica from yandex. [Link to yandex.metrica](https://appmetrica.yandex.ru/?ncrnd=9444) It's very simple to integrate yandex.metrica to your app and get all data about crashes and statistic (country, city, android version and so on).

[image: Screenshot]

[Link to console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)

Comment: Hi partner! Sorry for the delay. I have the app in beta versión, but I cannot see any errors (the app has had errors, obviously). Could it's be that it's a beta version?

Comment: Hi. I am not shure, that the reason is beta version. May be this is Developer Console bag. I recommend you to use yandex.metrica. It's easy to install to app and you always can see ALL ERRORS from all devices.

Comment: When I need to see errors, when I have beta-apps, I always use this library. It's powerful.When all bags left, I send new build to market without yandex.metrica (I need a minimum internet-traffic)

Comment: Hi partner! I'm testing yandex metrica and is awesome! But have a doubt yet... yandex metrica register ANR errors of app?

Comment: Hi again man, I'm testing it in a test project and works fine. But in my app, when YandexMetricaAndroid.YandexMetricaImplementation.Activate(this, "my api key", this.Application); is called, I get two times the message "Unfortunately, App was stopped", but my app is still running, and the YandexMetrica.Implementation.ReportEvent and YandexMetrica.Implementation.ReportError is not registering nothing.

Comment: Hi. I can't say, what's wrong, I need to see you code and logcat. Try to find Error message with reason at logcat and send to me, I will look at this. My email: russian.sit.company@gmail.com or ICQ: 688-050-073

Answer (score 0):

Well google offers one really powerful tool `"Firebase"` it provides great analytics and crash reporting. In addition to analytics and crashes it provides others utilities like `Cloud-Testing`, `Push Notifications` and many others.

Other popular solution is Crashlytics offered by twitter.